# signalR and gridview reload page in asp.net webform

Tags: signalr

How do I use the signal R when the information in the database has changed the entire page to reload?
Or how can one bind the grid view again?

Comment: Have you tried/searched anything so far?

Comment: Yes I searched.

Comment: So, does it change the entire page, or only the data in the grid view? Or is the grid view the entire page? Anyway, gridview is a server component, so when you open an **url**, it is build in server, transformed in html and delivered to browser (client). The data/grid in your browser is just html, so you need some javascript signalr client to receive an event from the server when that data is changed and persisted to database. When the event is received, you'd need to somehow trigger a reload of the page (in javascript). Does this help you?